# Stored procedure to suppress default values of '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

So I'm working on a system that uses default date values of '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' rather than allowing nulls.  I've got a stored procedure that displays all members of an association and the date and amounts charged to them.  If a member has not received charges, I need to display a zero amount and empty string for the date. I've tried every permutation of `CASE` and `CONVERT` I can think of, but I can't seem to suppress the default date. It's the column `trandate` I'm trying to manipulate.  Any pointers are greatly appreciated!  Here is my current code, and below that the current results.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ApplyCharges_GetAllAssociationsDebtors]
    @tCode  int,
    @AssnKey    int
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
    SELECT
        c.pkey,
        c.lname + ', ' + c.fname as 'Name',
        c.address1,
        c.address2,
        c.assnkey,
        cs.camount as 'LastAmt',
        coalesce(c.AssmtChrgAmt, 0) as 'DefaultAmt',
        cs.trancode,
        a.name as 'AssnName' ,
        a.assmtchrgamt,
        a.latefee,
        CASE
            WHEN cs.trandate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN ''
            ELSE cs.trandate 
        END AS lasttrandate,
        CASE a.assmtchrgfreq
            WHEN 'A' THEN 'Annual'
            WHEN 'D' THEN 'Daily'
            WHEN 'B' THEN 'Bi-Monthly'
            WHEN 'M' THEN 'Monthly'
            WHEN 'Q' THEN 'Quarterly'
            WHEN 'S' THEN 'Semi-Annual'
            WHEN 'T' THEN 'Tri-Annual'
            ELSE 'N/A'
        END 
        AS AssessmentFrequency
    FROM 
        Cases c LEFT OUTER JOIN CaseSumm cs 
            ON c.pkey = cs.casekey
        INNER JOIN vw_CaseSumm_GetLastpKeyByTrantype v 
            ON cs.pkey = v.pkey 
        INNER JOIN assnctrl a
            ON c.assnkey = a.pkey
    WHERE
        v.trancode = @tcode and v.assnkey = @assnkey and c.active = 1
    UNION
    SELECT c2.pkey,
        c2.lname + ', ' + c2.fname as 'Name',
        c2.address1,
        c2.address2,
        c2.assnkey,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        a.name as 'AssnName',
        a.assmtchrgamt,
        a.latefee,
        '',
        CASE a.assmtchrgfreq
            WHEN 'A' THEN 'Annual'
            WHEN 'D' THEN 'Daily'
            WHEN 'B' THEN 'Bi-Monthly'
            WHEN 'M' THEN 'Monthly'
            WHEN 'Q' THEN 'Quarterly'
            WHEN 'S' THEN 'Semi-Annual'
            WHEN 'T' THEN 'Tri-Annual'
            ELSE 'N/A'
        END 
        As AssessmentFrequency
    FROM 
        Cases c2 INNER JOIN AssnCtrl a
        ON c2.assnkey = a.pkey
    WHERE c2.assnkey = @assnkey and c2.active = 1
    and c2.pkey NOT IN 
        (SELECT casekey FROM vw_CaseSumm_GetLastpKeyByTrantype WHERE assnkey = @assnkey and trancode = @tcode)
    ORDER BY Name
```

Result example:

```
142373  Smith, John 1234 Main St.   84  0.00    0   0   Ashley Place Condominium, Inc.  333.00  0   1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 Tri-Annual
```

Comment: You are using a case expression to show '' when the date = 1/1/1900. The problem is because the column is a datetime and you seem to expect it to be a string. An empty string in sql server will implicitly cast to 1/1/1900. Change your case expression to return a NULL instead of ''.

Comment: Unless you really have very old dates in your database, it may also convenient just using the test mydate > '1902-01-01' or suchlike as these "null" date values can vary slightly depending upon the source of the pseudo-nulls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that all possible values of a CASE statement must have the same DataType, and the most restrictive possibility will be used.

You are trying to return an empty string in one case, but in the other case you return a DateTime type.  That means that the empty string will be implicitly converted to a DateTime, which will default to 1900-01-01.

If you CAST the datetime value to a string, then both sides will return a string and you will be able to return an empty string.   Like so:

```
CASE
    WHEN cs.trandate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN ''
    ELSE CONVERT(varchar(31),cs.trandate)
END AS lasttrandate,
```

Of course this is only a useful answer if you can accept a having a string for an output datatype for that column.  If you need the datatype to be a date-time, then you will have to accept the 1900-01-01 output and handle it in your front end.

Comment: Why not use NULLIF() and make the app smart enough to handle NULL? Better yet, use NULL in the database instead of this silly token value>

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
WHEN cs.trandate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN ''
```

into this

```
WHEN CAST(cs.trandate AS DATE) = '19000101' THEN NULL
```

Comparing date-times is always fraught with error for the same reason comparing floats is.  This just pulls the actual date part and does the comparison, which is good enough I think for your case.

Also, since the column type is 'datetime', the THEN '' will be cast to a date time, which will end up being "mindate"... or 1900-01-01.  You really want NULL here, and to adjust the rest of the query as necessary to deal with NULLs.

Comment: Nope, as pointed out above, the '' will be replaced by 1900-01-01.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying.  Updated my answer to reflect.

Comment: As pointed out, I get what you're saying... I was concentrating on the WHEN part, not the THEN part.  I've updated my answer to reflect.  The down-vote isn't really warranted, imho.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, thanks guys!  SO many great responses so quickly.  I tried them all, and in the end the suggestion from Tab Alleman hit the home run for me.  I did make a slight modification to
ELSE CONVERT(varchar(10),cs.trandate, 101) so that I can a short date in return.  Aside from that, this is exactly what I was looking for, and it makes perfect sense the way you explained it, Tab.

Thanks again to all who helped!